# Combine nested dictionaries in ansible

Tags: dictionary, ansible

I have 2 different dictionaries that contains application information I need to join together.

landscape_dictionary:

```
{
  "app_1": {
    "Category": "application",
    "SolutionID": "194833",
    "Availability": null,
    "Environment": "stage",
    "Vendor/Manufacturer": null
  },
  "app_2": false
}
```

app_info_dictionary:

```
{
  "app_1": {
    "app_id": "6886817",
    "owner": "owner1@nomail.com",
    "prod": [
      "server1"
    ],
    "stage": []
  },
  "app_2": {
    "app_id": "3415012",
    "owner": "owner2@nomail.com",
    "prod": [
      "server2"
    ],
    "stage": [
      "server3"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the code I'm using to join both dictionaries

```
- set_fact:
    uber_dict: "{{app_info_dictionary}}"

- set_fact:
    uber_dict: "{{ uber_dict | default ({}) | combine(new_item, recursive=true) }}"
  vars:
    new_item: "{ '{{item.key}}' : { 'landscape': '{{landscape_dictionary[item.key]|default(false)}}' } }"
  with_dict: "{{ uber_dict }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{item.key}}: {{item.value}}"
  with_dict: "{{uber_dict}}"
```

If the value in the landscape_dictionary is false it will add it to the uber_dict without problems. But if the value contains information, it fails.

This is the error:

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "|combine expects dictionaries, got u\"{ 'app_1' : { 'landscape': '{u'Category': u'application', u'SolutionID': u'194820', u'Availability': None, u'Environment': 'stage', u'Vendor/Manufacturer': None}' } }\""}
```

What could be the problem?
Do I need to do an extra combine when I set the var in the set_fact?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax is not legal, or at the very least doesn't do what you think:

```
new_item: "{ '{{item.key}}' : { 'landscape': '{{landscape_dictionary[item.key]|default(false)}}' } }"
```

Foremost, ansible will only auto-coerce **JSON** strings into a `dict`, but you have used **python** syntax.

Secondarily, the way to dynamically construct a `dict` is not to use jinja2 to build up text but rather use the fact that jinja2 is almost a programming language:

```
new_item: "{{
  {
    item.key: {
      'landscape': landscape_dictionary[item.key]|default(false)
    }
  }
}}"
```

Any time you find yourself with nested jinja2 interpolation blocks, that is a code smell that you are thinking about the problem too much as *text* (by nested, I mean `{{ something {{nested}} else }}`)

Comment: I realized a couple of minutes ago and I was going to answer. Thanks

Comment: For anyone from the Internet looking for the answer to: "How tp combine nested dictionaries in ansible", the answer is  `| combine(new_item, recursive=true)`.

Comment: @DustWolf `recursive=true` has been the magic that I have been looking for, for about 2 days! Ansible has some of the weirdest dict behaviour without it! It Sometimes extends, rewrites or rearranges your dict and which is does when is utterly bewildering. Thank you so much for the combine parameter that makes it actually work!

Answer (score 3):

As [@DustWolf notes in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841818/combine-nested-dictionaries-in-ansible/70011532#comment113385704_59843993),

> For anyone from the Internet looking for the answer to: "How tp combine nested dictionaries in ansible", the answer is `| combine(new_item, recursive=true)`

This solves a closely related issue that has baffled myself and my team for months.

I will demonstrate:

Code:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    my_default_values:
      key1: value1
      key2:
        a: 10
        b: 20
    my_custom_values:
      key3: value3
      key2:
        a: 30
    my_values: "{{ my_default_values | combine(my_custom_values, recursive=true) }}"
  tasks:
    - debug: var=my_default_values
    - debug: var=my_values
```

Output:

```
ok: [localhost] => 
  my_values:
    key1: value1
    key2:
      a: 30
    key3: value3
```

Note how `key2` was completely replaced, thus losing `key2.b`

We changed this to:

```
my_values: "{{ my_default_values | combine(my_custom_values, recursive=true) }}"
```

Output:

```
  my_values:
    key1: value1
    key2:
      a: 30
      b: 20
    key3: value3
```

Comment: Obviously, this is closely related to this question. As it's introducing a different problem, however, it may be worth posting instead as a Q&A, where you pose the question, then immediately post the solution. That may make it easier to find since the question will be specific to this problem.